# How to share the JWT Bearer Token Between the two service in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, jwt

I want to publish my API to a load-balanced environment，but the JWT bearer authentication is not working in load-balanced.

Comment: Hey, you'll need to provide some more details before anyone can help you here, see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). How are you load balancing, where are you checking the token, what do you mean by "not working" etc.?

Comment: Hi,I want to know,How to share JWT Tokens between two sites?

Comment: You should pass the JWT as part of your request headers (preferably the "Authorization" header). It shouldn't matter if your application is load balanced or not. Which ever server receives the request, will also receive all the request headers including your Authorization header with the JWT as its value.